# how to start or run matlab in fedora 20?

Tags: matlab, fedora

I got matlab installed in fedora 20, but I do not know how to run it? I tried typing matlab in the teminal, but it does not recognize the command. I am not able to see matlab icon in the apps also. How can I start using it??

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/146374/where-is-my-software-installed-in-linux

Comment: @rayryeng I am able to locate matlab, path is /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB, but I dont know what to do after that

Comment: @rayryeng I dont know on how to start the app, I have used matlab only in windows, so I have no idea on how to start it..

Comment: When you're in the directory.... Type in matlab?

Comment: @rayryeng I traversed till glnxa64 folder and typed in matlab, it does not work

Comment: oops!  I forgot to tell you to go to the bin folder.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB must be launched from the command line on Linux.

If you completed installation as root user, you may have had the option to install symbolic links to MATLAB in a folder on your system path. If you selected to install these links you can launch MATLAB from the command line, regardless of current working directory, by typing the command:

```
user@host$> matlab
```

If this does not work, or if you did not install the symbolic links during installation, you must launch MATLAB by specifying the full path to the MATLAB start script:

```
user@host$> cd $MATLABROOT/bin
```

where $MATLABROOT is the full path to your MATLAB installation directory, ex:

```
/usr/local/matlab/R2009b
```

then launch MATLAB using the following command:

```
user@host$> ./matlab
```

With reference to: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93739-how-do-i-launch-matlab-on-linux

Comment: @lakesh, I tried doing what you said; however, it does not show anything (not even an error), and Matlab doesn't start.